# Check if a string contains any items of an set of strings?

Tags: python

I have a text file that has a sentence at each line. And I have a word list. I just want to get only the sentences which contain at least one word from the list. Is there a pythonic way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried? You should know we won't write code for you. At least not for free.

Answer (score 4):

```
sentences = [line for line in f if any(word in line for word in word_list)]
```

Here `f` would be your file object, for example you could replace it with `open('file.txt')` if `file.txt` was the name of your file and it was located in the same directory as the script.

Answer (score 2):

Using `set.intersection`:

```
with open('file') as f:
    [line for line in f if set(line.lower().split()).itersection(word_set)]
```

or with `filter`:

```
filter(lambda x:word_set.intersection(set(x.lower().split())),f)
```

Comment: @user:1199589  `intersection` or `itersection`?

Answer (score 1):

this will give you a start:

```
words = ['a', 'and', 'foo']
infile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
match_sentences = []

for line in infile.readlines():
    # check for words in this line
    # if match, append to match_sentences list
```